# creating and signing transaction

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I am looking a way to create signed transaction using c++ libs from aleth. I have this transaction:

```
{
  from: "0025defd0f341b7f673f84b81c8416d58df29045",
  to: "0078fca08eacba4f0313e43366e6c3ecb21fb8eb",
  gasLimit: "21000",
  gasPrice: "200",
  nonce: "0",
  value: "10000000000",
}
```

As I understand i can sign it using 'aleth-key sign', but it requires hex representation of transaction. How can i get it? Can I use for this purposes sha3 and rpl? Which steps I have to do for getting hex representation?